# How can I install new mouse drivers on HP Desktop retail edition

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers

I recently upgraded my HP rp5800 from windows 7 to windows 10 and a few weeks later, the mice drivers stopped working. I can seem to find the right drivers from the internet and I am unable to run some applications with just the keyboard. Does anyone know how I can get mouse to work again. The device shows `HID Compliant Mouse` but the it says drivers are not installed. Please help

Comment: Use the HP Driver Update App and see if there are drivers for Windows 10.

Comment: @John i've tried, they don't have those drivers for windows 10

Comment: Then you may need to keep the machine at Windows 7 (security risk) and so it may be time for a new machine.

Comment: Also try a USB mouse.  That may work and allow Windows 10 to work. Windows 10 is moving to end of life, so this may get you another year or two.

Comment: HP have drivers for XP, 7 & 8. https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-rp5800-retail-system/5081352 There is no support at all for Windows 10. According to https://icecat.biz/p/hp/qc416ea/pcs-workstations-0886111969579-rp5800-11295795.html support ended in 2011. If the mouse is a standard HID-compliant device, it should be supported anyway.